# insert using CTEs in snowflake

Tags: sql, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, snowflake-schema

I want to insert some of the resulting columns into another table.

```
SELECT
        d_objects."OBJECT_GROUP"  AS "d_objects.object_group",
        (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "d_dates.date_date",
        COALESCE(SUM(( f_traffic."MEDIA_CONTENT_START"  ) ), 0) AS "f_traffic.sum_content_media_views",
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ( d_platforms."PLATFORM"  ) = 'Desktop' THEN ( f_traffic."MEDIA_START" ) ELSE NULL END), 0) AS media_views_web,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ( d_platforms."PLATFORM"  ) = 'Mobile' THEN ( f_traffic."MEDIA_START" ) ELSE NULL END), 0) AS media_views_mobile,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ( d_platforms."PLATFORM"  ) = 'App' THEN ( f_traffic."MEDIA_START" ) ELSE NULL END), 0) AS media_views_app
    FROM DATA_MART.F_TRAFFIC  AS f_traffic
    INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_DATES  AS d_dates ON (f_traffic."WH_DATE_ID") = (d_dates."ID")
    INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_OBJECTS  AS d_objects ON
                 (f_traffic."D_OBJECTS_ID") = (d_objects."ID")
    INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_PLATFORMS  AS d_platforms ON (f_traffic."D_PLATFORMS_ID") = (d_platforms."ID")
    LEFT JOIN DATA_MART.D_CONTENT_MEDIA  AS d_content_media ON (f_traffic."D_CONTENT_MEDIA_ID")  = (d_content_media."ID")
    WHERE ((f_traffic."MEDIA_TYPE" ) <> 'video : vicki' AND (f_traffic."MEDIA_TYPE" ) <> 'audio' AND (f_traffic."MEDIA_TYPE" ) <> 'trailer' OR (f_traffic."MEDIA_TYPE" ) IS NULL) AND (((( d_dates."DAY"  ) >= ((TO_DATE(DATEADD('day', -28, CURRENT_DATE())))) AND ( d_dates."DAY"  ) < ((TO_DATE(DATEADD('day', 28, DATEADD('day', -28, CURRENT_DATE()))))))) AND (d_objects."OBJECT_GROUP" ) = 'BILD') AND ((d_objects."OBJECT_NAME" ) IN ('BILD', 'SPORT BILD') AND ((d_content_media."ADOBE_CONTENT_TYPE" ) = 'video' AND ((lower(d_content_media."TAXONOMY_LIST") ) NOT LIKE '%vicki%' OR (lower(d_content_media."TAXONOMY_LIST") ) IS NULL)))
    GROUP BY
        (TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" )),
        1
    ORDER BY
        2 DESC
)
```

The insert statement could look like this:

```
INSERT INTO PROD_DWH.FOUNDRY_REPORTING.bild_daily_traffic (D_DATES, SUM_CONTENT_MEDIA_VIEWS, MEDIA_VIEWS_MOBILE, MEDIA_VIEWS_APP, REPORT_DATE, REPORT_ID, KPI_NAME)
```

This means I will once again have to select from the previous select statement if i do not want to insert all columns. Hence, i want to do the insert using a CTE but I haven't been able to figure out the **correct syntax to do an insert using a CTE.**

Comment: What is your goal here?  An `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` from a CTE certainly should work.

Comment: yes, but I am uncertain about the syntax for a CTE here @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this

```
insert into mytable 
with cte as (above select SQL)
select * from cte
```

Also while inserting, you can remove order by clause.
Example -

```
insert into mytable 
with cte as (select '2022-01-01' union select '2022-02-01' )
select * from cte
```

EDIT :

Replying to your comment, yes you can insert into multiple columns like below example. You can even use different logic for different columns.

```
insert into mytable (col1,col2, col3)
with cte as (
select '2022-01-01' as col1, 'john' as col2, 500 as col3 union 
select '2022-02-01' as col1, 'jane' as col2, 100 as col3 
)
select * from cte
```

But if you are looking to insert into two different table, that is not possible.

Comment: can we also do two inserts with a single cte?

Comment: yes, you can do union all.

Comment: how exactly? could you give an example? by two inserts i mean inserting data into different columns (not the same)

Comment: replied. If you have some other scenario, could you pls post some example?